# largeTitles navigationItem bottom constraint not translated during height increases when you pull down

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uinavigationbar, ios11

I am using largeTitles for my navigationItem in a viewController which contains a tableView.

When I pull down on the tableView that is scrolled to the top, the navigation bar nicely increases height and returns to the original height when I let go.  The navigationBar height will continue to increase as I drag down.

The tableView content also drags down but the view in between the navigationBar and the tableView (customView) stays put and there is just an empty space there until the drag stops and the navigationBar returns to it's original place.

Since the top of the customView is pinned to the safeArea I would expect the behavior to let it move down with the bottom of the navigationBar.

I can the desired effect by overriding the scrollViewDidScroll method for the tableView but wondering if there is an easier way to do this.